# How to check if LocationMatch regex is working?

Tags: apache-2.4, regex

I have location match regex

```
ScriptAlias /script /var/www/somescript.bash
Action some-handler /script virtual
<LocationMatch "/(?:\w+:)?\/\/[^\/]+([^?#]+)/">
    SetHandler some-handler
</LocationMatch>
```

Now when test that regex https://regex101.com/r/lO0aV1/1 you can see that location is matched but somescript.bash is never executed.

mod_actions are on by the way.

In error log I do not see anything. In access log I got 404.

How can I check that this regex is working? Is there anyway that I can  log that?

Comment: i am not sure that you can execute bash directly from apache, anyway, i found this : http://serverfault.com/questions/149153/how-to-run-linux-bash-script-from-web-browser

Comment: @Froggiz sure you can. That is ScriptAlias for you just have to set suexec user/group. But my question was more how can I be sure that regex is working beside obvious that is not at the momment? How to log that or something?

Comment: for the log you can try to add in your web configuration "ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log" "LogLevel warn" (or info) "CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined" "RewriteLogLevel 9" RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewritelog" ... but as you get a 404 error, for me that mean that the page isn't considered as being accessible by the client trought apache(if the reg ex is correct)

Comment: No need to escape forward slashes there, and the locationmatch only matches against the path component of the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a CustomLog, with e.g.:

```
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/mylog.log" "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b what:%{INDICATOR_VAR}e"
```

and use SetEnv to set the INDICATOR_VAR:

```
<LocationMatch ...>
    SetEnv INDICATOR_VAR "OK"
</LocationMatch>
```

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to check that a LocationMatch works is to put a simple mod_headers directive in it and dump the response headers on a test client.  e.g. `Header set X-DEBUG foo`